# What am I doing wrong? Rowspan won't change

Tags: java, itext

I'm fairly new to Java/iText and I'm having trouble with getting my Rowspan(3) to merge. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I am looking for

[image]

This is what I am getting. I'm trying to merge rows 1, 2, and 3 into a single row.

This is my current table

[image]

```
      table1.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ACTUALS", fonti));
        cell.setColspan(9);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table1.addCell(cell);
        table1.completeRow();

        table1.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table1.getDefaultCell().setRowspan(3);
        table1.addCell(new Phrase("1"));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.addCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table1.completeRow();
```

Comment: Can you make a drawing that shows what the table should look like? Your  code looks awkward. It doesn't look logical.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I edited my original post and added an image of what I am trying to create. I can't seem to get my rows to merge.

Comment: *I can't seem to get my rows to merge.* - On the contrary, you have merged the rows. But even with merged rows, the cells are not larger than necessary for their content unless you explicitly set cell sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you've shared, it looks as if you want to change the height of the cells. To achieve this, you don't change the height, but you change the rowspan. That is not what rowspan is for. Rowspan should only be used if you want a specific cell to span multiple rows when adjacent cells span only one row.

Changing the rowspan of *all the cells in the same row* doesn't make any sense. Whether all the cells in a row span only one row or three rows doesn't make any difference in the visual representation of the row.

If you want to change the height of a row, you need to use a method that changes the height. See [How do setMinimumSize() and setFixedSize() interact?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-do-setminimumsize-and-setfixedsize-interact) to find out which two methods you can choose from.

If a typical row is 20 user units height, use this to make a row thrice as heigh:

```
cell.setMinimumHeight(60);
```

You can also use:

```
cell.setFixedHeight(60);
```

but that's more dangerous as the latter method can cause content to be dropped.